# Certain pages footnotes will not show. Word 2016 PC

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document I am working on and there area number of footnotes. What is happening is that two pages don't show the footnotes at the bottom, but all other pages do. The footnotes still exist because I can mouse over the reference number and it shows. I can also change the margins from Narrow, to Normal and the footnote will appear. However, it shows up on the next page, and the page has no other text on it. It is blank other than header, footer, and footnote. Then the text resumes on the next page. I have tried changing the spacing to exact as I had seen that as a possible solution but that did not work either. I also tried changing the footnote formatting so that the lines would stay together, and that did not work. I have tried deleting all footnotes and adding them back in.
This is a legal document so I cannot change the reference location. There are no tables involved.

- Footnotes 1-4 work. They are on page 1 of the document
- Footnotes 5 and 6 do not work. They are on page 2 of the document but don't display at all.
- Footnote 7    works. It is on Page 3
- Footnote 8-12 work and are on page 4.
- Footnote    13 does not work. It is on a page by itself.
- Footnote 14 works.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yth8btvto7567pk/part8%20final.docx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the document and I think that I have found your problem.

I suggest doing this :

- Select the entire document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Right-click any text and choose *Paragraph ...*
- Open the tab of *Line and Page Breaks*
- Click twice the the check-boxes of *Keep with next* and *Keep lines together*
  so they become unchecked
- Click OK

Verify well the document, checking for orphaned titles at the bottom of the page.
If you would like to attach the title to the following text,
so they appear on the same page, select both
and set the above check-boxes.